# The program wont work for n>9... It works fine when n is a static expression

Tags: c, arrays

if we take n>9 then it wont input the elements with arr[n] where n>9.
The program works fine if n is constant ..
whats wrong in program.
please help...
i complied and run it in windows using mingw shell

```
/* Binary Search Program */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int n,arr[n],i,j,temp;
    printf("Enter The number of elements in array : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the %d elements of array :\n",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }

    printf("The Unsorted array is :\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    }
    /* BOUBBLE SORTING */

    for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n-1-j;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
            {
                temp=arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1]=arr[i];
                arr[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The sorted array is :\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 int n,arr[n],i,j,temp;
```

The size of `arr` has an indeterminate value because `n` is not initialized.

Declare `arr` after your `scanf("%d",&n)`  call.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work in C, because you can only declare a new variable at beginning of a block.

Comment: @Zaffy; C99 allow mixed type declarations.

Comment: @haccks Oh, I see, great!

Answer (score 3):

You are using variable length arrays. On run time compiler did't know about `n` when you declare `arr[n]` before inputting `n`. You have to declare `arr` after inputting `n`.

Try this

```
int n,i,j,temp;
printf("Enter The number of elements in array : ");
scanf("%d",&n);
int arr[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare array arr under the `scanf("%d",&n);` at the beginning of new block or allocate memory with `n * sizeof(int)` bytes